# ls all files in directory plus all files in directories one level down

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, ls

Ok I have the following situation.

Caps are directories, lowercase are files.

```
A/aa
B/bb
C/cc
D/dd
D/E/ddd
D/F/G/dddd
a
b
c
d
```

I want to do a ls that lists

```
a
b
c
d
A/aa
B/bb
C/cc
D/dd
```

but not either

```
D/E/ddd
D/F/G/dddd
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `find` to find only files in the current directory or one directory down:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 2  -type f
```

Demo:

```
# Show whole directory structure, digits are files, letters are folders. 
$  find .
.
./1
./2
./3
./4
./A
./A/11
./B
./B/22
./C
./C/33
./D
./D/44
./D/E
./D/F
./D/F/444
./D/F/G
./D/F/G/4444

# Find only files at a maximum depth of 2
$  find . -maxdepth 2  -type f
./1
./2
./3
./4
./A/11
./B/22
./C/33
./D/44
```

Answer (score 3):

This one lists everything inside directories in your current working dir: `ls -l */`

A combination of two commands will include files in your current directory as well: `ls -l */; ls -l`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with find:

```
find . -maxdepth 2
```

Comment: This overmatches, it finds directory as well as files.